# Password Reset in Lumen 5.3

Tags: laravel-5.3, lumen, lumen-5.3

I'm trying to create a PasswordReset API in Lumen 5.3.

I've the same setup from a default Laravel 5.3 app.

```
$app->post('/password/email', 'PasswordController@postEmail');
$app->post('/password/reset/{token}', 'PasswordController@postReset');
```

and in the user Model I've overridden the method as follows:

```
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token)
{
        $this->notify(new ResetPasswordNotification($token));
}
```

I've manually pulled in the Notification package for Lumen 5.3

But, I'm getting the following error:

```
BindingResolutionException in Container.php line 763:
Target [Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer] is not instantiable while building [Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\MailChannel].
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I have same issue, did you find any solution

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line in your `bootstrap/app.php`

```
$app->alias('mailer', \Illuminate\Contracts\Mail\Mailer::class);
```